# How to spawn and post to a page and then redirect to another

Tags: asp.net

from my asp.net page I am spawning a page using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write. After it is done, I want to redirect to another page. It doesn't work. If I had Response.Redirect at the end, then it redirects immediately without spawning the page. Partial code is shown below:

```
string targetUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"].ToString();


System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(
"<form name='newForm' target='_blank' method=post action=" + targetUrl + " >");

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(
string.Format("<input type=text name=\"txtAcctNumber\" value=\"{0}\">",
                                  ViewState["GroupNumber"].ToString()));

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(
 string.Format("<input type=text name=\"txtAmountDue\" value=\"{0}\">",       txtAmountDue.Text));

 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</form>");
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</body>");

 Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>document.forms[0].submit();</SCRIPT>");
 Response.Clear();
 Response.Redirect("~/PremiumPayment/InvoiceSearch.aspx");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Response.Redirect cause a `ThreadAbourException` sends a http 302 response to the client. 
It is meant for immediate redirection.

You should use the meta tags to show your users a message and then redirect.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=http://mysite/PremiumPayment/InvoiceSearch.aspx" />
```

This will redirect your users to the new page after 10 seconds.